# multigrid 2-d restriction and interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, python, multigrid

How to build a restriction or interpolation matrices for 2-d problem for V-cycle multigrid. I read a lot of references about it, they only shows the coefficients matrix like following.
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1/16 & 1/8 & 1/16 \\
        1/8 & 1/4 & 1/8 \\
        1/16 & 1/8 & 1/4 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
For 1-d cases, I can easily build a interpolation matrix like(3 to 5):
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 &  &  \\
        2 &  &  \\
        1 & 1 & \\
 &2  &  \\
 & 1 &  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

and do the transpose to get the restriction matrix and get the coarser mesh by A2h = RAI. And that only work for 1-D case. Here's the python code I used to do the multigrid example:
https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/gmgsolve/gmgsolve.py

For the 2-d case, I think I am supposed to use bilinear interpolation. But I don't know what the restriction and interpolation matrix look like. Does any one could show me a example, just like 9 to 5 restriction for 2-d case?

Comment: That is up to you. It depends on how you choose to arrange your data in the vector that the filtering operation represented by the matrix multiplication will work on.

Comment: The only thing you can say without having specified a vectorization is that each row of your matrix will contain the filter coefficients in the particular positions the filter will work for the output of that pixel. Before having picked an order to vectorize the 2D data then you just won't know those positions.